# Como abrir pdf que esta localizado em uma pasta no projeto no html?

Tags: html, python, django

Estou tentando abrir um arquivo pdf que está localizado em uma pasta dentro do projeto, mas não esta dando certo.

Segui algumas sugestões e tentei isso:

```
<a href="../../media/Novo_Documento_2017-09-13_18.19.55_20170913182145649.pdf"   target="_blank">pdf_001</a>
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é abrir o pdf que está localizado nessa pasta media no navegador.

Comment: coloca o código de como você esta fazendo, e o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo ( http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar ( http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ).

Answer (score 0):

Penso que seja isso que pretende, abrir o pdf directamente no navegador!

```
<iframe src="../../media/Novo_Documento_2017-09-13_18.19.55_20170913182145649.pdf" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```